# Google Strange Issue

Tags: google

In a server running for last 8 months we had been accessing this URL: https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/components-2.json through `curl`. A few days ago it stopped working suddenly and says

> 404. That's an error. That's all we know.

[image]

But the most strange part it this is happening on this only machine only. All other machines are able to access it without a problem. This problem machine is able to access all other internet sites including google, gmail etc.

All machines are running CentOS 6.4.

---

These are two curl output when get the json file

**This is the machine which fails:**

```
# curl -v https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/components-2.json
* About to connect() to dl.google.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 4.59.40.88... connected
* Connected to dl.google.com (4.59.40.88) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
* Server certificate:
*   subject: CN=*.google.com,O=Google Inc,L=Mountain View,ST=California,C=US
*   start date: Mar 25 14:48:48 2015 GMT
*   expire date: Jun 23 00:00:00 2015 GMT
*   common name: *.google.com
*   issuer: CN=Google Internet Authority G2,O=Google Inc,C=US
> GET /dl/cloudsdk/release/components-2.json HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.16.2.3 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: dl.google.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Content-Length: 1364
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Server: downloads
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Date: Wed, 15 Apr 2015 09:32:31 GMT
```

**This is the machine which succeeds:**

```
# curl -v https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/components-2.json
* About to connect() to dl.google.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 74.125.141.136... connected
* Connected to dl.google.com (74.125.141.136) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
* Server certificate:
*   subject: CN=*.google.com,O=Google Inc,L=Mountain View,ST=California,C=US
*   start date: Mar 25 15:57:18 2015 GMT
*   expire date: Jun 23 00:00:00 2015 GMT
*   common name: *.google.com
*   issuer: CN=Google Internet Authority G2,O=Google Inc,C=US
> GET /dl/cloudsdk/release/components-2.json HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.13.6.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: dl.google.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 48061
< Content-Type: application/json
< Etag: "526ef"
< Expires: Thu, 16 Apr 2015 02:32:38 PDT
< Last-Modified: Thu, 09 Apr 2015 16:52:00 GMT
< Server: downloads
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Date: Wed, 15 Apr 2015 09:32:38 GMT
< Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=0.5
```

Comment: It is working from all other machines in the same data center.  Each machine has a different public IP address. I tried from other machines in different countries and it is working. The problem machine is in the US.

Comment: OK, maybe it is not national censorship then. The US doesn't censor Google....most of the time :)

Comment: Any chances that Google is blocking it?

Comment: Also you might want to try this alternative URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/components-2.json. You might be hitting a broken mirror

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I see a word block in headers curl -v https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/components-2.json
* About to connect() to dl.google.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 4.59.40.103... connected
* Connected to dl.google.com (4.59.40.103) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=*.google.com,O=Google Inc,L=Mountain View,ST=California,C=US
*       start date: Mar 25 14:48:48 2015 GMT
*       expire date: Jun 23

Comment: Hmm, you've probably already considered this, but is there an http caching system between the machine and the Internet that could be re sending the same 404 over and over?

Comment: I see a difference in User agent line in the server which fails and the server which succeeds. I am posting in reply as this comment box doesn't allow that much characters.

Comment: 4.59.40.88 etc. are not Google-owned IP addresses. If the certificate is valid, and this is an edge cache, then Google themselves are at fault.

Comment: I specified a hard coded IP and same problem: # curl -v https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/components-2.json
* About to connect() to dl.google.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 74.125.141.136... connected
* Connected to dl.google.com (74.125.141.136) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.google.com,O=Google Inc,L=Mountain View,ST=California,C=US
*  start date: Mar 25 15:57:18 2015 GMT
........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved when we changed the Public IP from a different IP block. Looks like Google wasn't liking the IP anymore.